# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'xController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular  v1.4.2, and keep getting "**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'accountRegisterCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**" below is my controller defination

```
(function(app) {

    'use strict';

    function accountRegisterCtrl($scope, $window) {

       //........

        $scope.previous = function () {
            $window.history.back();
        }
    }

    app.controller('accountRegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', accountRegisterCtrl]);

}(angular.module('accountRegister')));
```

can any body be of help!

Comment: Just use an inline function instead and you'll get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in general if you misspeled the controller from your HTML view or your route definitions :

```
<div data-ng-controller="accountRegisterCtl"> <!-- WRONG -->
    // ui stuff ...
</div>
```

Here the `accountRegisterCtl` controller is called during the compilation step, but it didn't exists because its misspelled: `accountRegisterCtrl` is the correct controller name.

```
<div data-ng-controller="accountRegisterCrtl"> <!-- CORRECT -->
    // ui stuff ...
</div>
```

Or your `controller.js` is not injected in your `index.html`